# JS Hooking Custom Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a client side script for my .NET control. The script hooks all the :checkbox items to trigger an event called **OnOptionItemSelected**.

```
function ControlScript() {

    this.OnOptionItemSelected = function (e) { /* do something */ }
    this.Configure = function () {
        // hook change event of items in the input control          
        $('#' + this.ControlID).find(":radio, :checkbox")
                        .on("change", this, this.OnOptionItemSelected);
    }        
}
```

*(Some pieces of code removed)*
In another place on the page, I get the client side script for a particular control and need to hook the **OnOptionItemSelected** event. How would I hook this event?

```
var script = GetScriptForControl(ID);
if (script)
  // hook script.OnOptionItemSelected to a custom function ????
```

Comment: your code isn't clear enough. it not return a value. please be more clear

Answer (score 0):

I will suppose that the GetScriptForControl return a instance of ControlScript. So what i would do is:

```
if(script) { 
  oldOptionItemSelected = script.OnOptionItemSelected
  script.OnOptionItemSelected = function(ev) { 
    /* before OptionItemSelected code HERE */ 
    oldOptionItemSelected.call(script,ev);
    /* after OptionItemSelected code  HERE */ 
  };
  /* rebind the events */
  script.Configure();
}
```

Comment: you'll need a "rebind" that will off the change events and  bind the onOptionItemSelected again after the item loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found an answer that better suits my needs:

```
function ControlClientSide()
{    
    this.CheckBoxClicked = function() { }        
    this.Configure = function() {        
        $('#checkBox100').change(function() { $(this).triggerHandler("CheckBoxClicked"); }.bind(this));   
    };
    this.Configure();
};

var x = new ControlClientSide();
$(x).on("CheckBoxClicked", function() { alert( this.constructor.name + ' Hi'); })
    .on("CheckBoxClicked", function() { alert( this.constructor.name + ' Hi2'); });
```

The only thing I cant figure out is how to get "this" to be the checkbox in the "CheckBoxClicked" event handlers. Currently it is set to the ControlClientSide function.

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/KC5RH/3/